# Retrofti 2: Multiple Retrofit annotations found, only one allowed. (parameter #1)

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am facing some trouble/confusion while framing the request in Retrofit 2 and following is my issue i.e; Could some one please suggest how to add following "**payload?file**" while framing request

```
BaseUrl : https://testserver.testbox.com/

Full URL : https://testserver.testbox.com/payload?file=Config/testApp_Android_3.2_IN_config.json


@GET("Config/testApp_Android_{version}_{country}_config.json")
                    fun getConfig(
                        @Query("file")
                        @Path("version") applicationVersion: String,
                        @Path("country") applicationCountry: String
                    ): Observable<Config>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a fileName parameter(or parameter name you prefer) in your `getConfig()` method like below:

```
BaseUrl : https://testserver.testbox.com/

Full URL : https://testserver.testbox.com/payload?file=Config/testApp_Android_3.2_IN_config.json


@GET("/payload")
fun getConfig(@Query("file") fileName:String): Observable<Config>
```

then build and pass fileName parameter from class where you call getConfig(fileName)

```
var applicationVersion = "Android_3.2"
var applicationCountry = "IN"

val fileName = "Config/testApp_Android_$applicationVersion_$applicationCountry_config.json"
getConfig(fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you, any how I implemented it.